# pdfLaTeX works fine; pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX returns error. There is nothing in document but \documentclass, \begin and \end document and a word

Tags: pdftex, compiling, compilation-error, makeindex, undefined

I am using Texworks Version 0.6.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit). Originally I had a bibliography but I have taken it out and the error is the same.

I am running a file containing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

pdfLaTeX gives:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350
> 64-bit) entering extended mode (WorkedExample.txt LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
> Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls" Document
> Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
> (WorkedExample.aux)
> [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
> (WorkedExample.aux) )<C :/Program Files/MiKTeX
> 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb> Output written on WorkedExample.pdf (1 page, 11236 bytes). SyncTeX written on
> WorkedExample.synctex.gz. Transcript written on WorkedExample.log.

pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX gives error:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350
> 64-bit) entering extended mode (C:/Bugs/WorkedExample.txt ! Undefined
> control sequence. l.1 \documentclass
> {article} ?

MakeIndex (alone) gives:

> Couldn't find input index file WorkedExample nor WorkedExample.idx.
> Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

BibTeX gives:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) The top-level
> auxiliary file: WorkedExample.aux I found no \citation
> commands---while reading file WorkedExample.aux I found no \bibdata
> command---while reading file WorkedExample.aux I found no \bibstyle
> command---while reading file WorkedExample.aux (There were 3 error
> messages)

But worked fine when I had a citation present so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: The last two are just warnings as they have no data to work on. The `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX gives error:` seems to indicate that it is configured incorrectly, it seems it is running `pdftex` not `pdflatex`.

Comment: Yes I noticed that but both **pdfLaTeX** and **pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX** are using pdftex so why does one work and not the other? If that is the problem how do I change them to run pdflatex? I have looked at Tool Configuration and **pdfLaTeX** is using the program _miktex-pdftex.exe_ and **pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX** is using _texify.exe_. Thanks.@daleif

Comment: pdflatex is a special call to pdftex with a given format. Since the the latter example you give gives error on `\documentclass` it is a clear indication that the latex format is not being used in that call.

Comment: Why does you document have `txt` extension rather than `tex`. This really isn't a great idea. [Edit: As you discovered.]

Answer (score 0):

The document was saved as WorkedExample.txt, when saved as WorkedExample.tex or WorkedExample.ltx it compiles fine.